# R replacing value if it matches a value in second data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I'm relativly new to R , hope you can help me :)

I have two dataframes, one main DF and the second one that sets a condition (first column) and the value by which the value in the main DF should be replaced (second column).

So for example the value "110" in the column "hp" of the mtcars dataframe should be replaced by the value "3"

```
df1 <- mtcars

first_column <- c(110, 93, 65)
second_column <- c(3, 2, 1)
df2 <- data.frame(first_column, second_column)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can loop across the numeric columns, `match` the column value with 'first_column' of 'df2' to get the index, use that index to replace with the 'second_column' values (by default, non-matching elements are returned NA in `match`), then we use `coalesce` to replace those NA elements with the original data column values

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% 
   mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ coalesce(df2$second_column[match(., 
           df2$first_column)], .)))
```

Comment: Hi, this worked great thank you! Do you know where I can specify this condition if I only want to use that for column "hp" in the mtcars DF?

Comment: @TomBandmann if there is only a single column, you don't need `across` i.e. `mtcars %>% mutate(hp = coalesce(df2$second_column[match(hp, df2$first_column)], hp))`

Comment: works! :) thank you very much for your quick reply, appreciate ur help